# Como validar o schema JSON em C#?

Tags: c#, json

Segue json (tem apenas 1 erro, pode ter vários erros):

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "XX-55",
      "path": "customer.id",
      "description": "Cliente não encontrado"
    }
  ]
}
```

Outro exemplo do retorno: (Vários erros)

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "XD-011",
      "path": "items[0].product",
      "description": "Informe o nome do produto"
    },
    {
      "path": "items[0].quantity",
      "description": "must be between 1 and 999999"
    },
    {
      "code": "BJ-009",
      "path": "items[0].price",
      "description": "Todos os valores devem ser maiores que zero"
    }
  ]
}
```

Como eu posso saber se o schema é desse formato ? Porque o código do retorno pode vir diferente do código acima json. O que me interessa é o código json acima.

Estou usando `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` para converter, mas o schemma pode ser diferente. Como eu posso saber no string tem desse formato: erros, code, path e description ?

Comment: Consegue saber à partida como o `schema` está estruturado? Ou seja, tem, em algum lado do seu código, a definição do `schema`?

Comment: @JoãoMartins Não, ele somente retorna assim:  `{"errors":[{"code":"XX-55","path":"customer.id","description":"Cliente não encontrado"}]}`

Comment: Tem biblioteca pronta para isso: https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema

Comment: Só não consigo fazer ela funcionar :/

Comment: Certo, essa biblioteca ia dizer-lhe para testar, mas para isso precisa obrigatoriamente de saber qual a estrutura do `schema` antes de o poder validar.

Comment: @JoãoMartins pior que não tem, somente aquele código acima mesmo.

Comment: @JoãoMartins isso não serve: https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-json-to-schema-converter ?

Comment: Funciona, mas é um conversor _online_. Teria que incluir algo do género na sua aplicação. Pode receber qualquer `schema`? E não sabe quantos ou quais antes, certo?

Comment: @JoãoMartins talvez existe outra forma de fazer isso sem utilizar essa biblioteca, ou seja sem saber a estrutura do schema. Só aquele código acima Json que me retorna. Eu não sei quantos ou quais antes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma é criar um deserializador usando a biblioteca [Newtonsoft](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json).

O primeiro passo é gerar as classes que representam o objeto JSON. Um jeito de fazer isso é usar um serviço online ou por ser um objeto simples você poderia inferir os atributos e propriedades. Eu gerei [esse aqui](https://app.quicktype.io?share=YAoMJQPQ9nnc3dbl4n18) com o seu exemplo.

```
namespace QuickType
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Globalization;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

    public partial class Root
    {
        [JsonProperty("errors")]
        public Error[] Errors { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Error
    {
        [JsonProperty("code", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Code { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("path")]
        public string Path { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Root
    {
        public static Root FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json, QuickType.Converter.Settings);
    }

    public static class Serialize
    {
        public static string ToJson(this Root self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, QuickType.Converter.Settings);
    }

    internal static class Converter
    {
        public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
            Converters = {
                new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
            },
        };
    }
}
```

Agora você já tem a classe `Root` que representam o seu objeto.

Então você usa o método `FromJson` da classe para converter a string que tem o JSON em objeto.

```
var myJson = Root.FromJson("sua string com os dados do JSON");
if (myJson.Errors != null) 
{
    // Indica que o objeto foi deserializado e contem o item "Errors" no root.
}
```

Você pode incrementar o código para verificar se não vai ocorrer nenhuma `Exception` se sua entrada puder ser qualquer coisa, mas no geral se for um objeto JSON ele vai tentar deserializar.